# Ignore Raycast object in front?

Tags: unity, dotween

There are 2 balls. These balls move right, left, forward and backward with swipe motions. I move it with dotween according to the swipe movement. If Raycast touches the wall, that's the position of the ball. But, since I use 2 balls, the raycast touches the other ball and stays in the position of the ball in front of it. What I want is that, it will not raycast the ball in front of him, it will only see the wall. But in this case, too, he gets into the ball. If the ball in front of it hit the wall, I want it to be one unit behind him. It looks better in the photo. What I want is exactly as in the photo. You can see the balls in the red circle.

[image]

Comment: Layer mask may help you. `Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, distance, layer_mask). `  [document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and [similar example](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1108781/set-ray-only-when-raycast-a-specific-layer.html)

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz As I mentioned, if I turn off the layer of the ball, the balls get into each other.

Comment: Sounds like you want to raycast twice. Once with a mask to only detect walls, once with a mask to only detect balls. If you detect a ball hit, you adjust your approach distance to the wall accordingly.